# PayPal Express Module Rejecting API Call

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

There is this error when finalizing an order:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Method Specified is not Supported (#81002: Unspecified Method).

The `exception.log` says:

```
2014-12-09T16:04:38+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway errors: Array Correlation ID: . Version: .' in /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:1062
Stack trace:
#0 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1008): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->_handleCallErrors(Array)
#1 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(616): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('SetExpressCheck...', Array)
#2 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(381): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callSetExpressCheckout()
#3 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(108): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->start('http://magentod...', 'http://magentod...', false)
#4 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->startAction()
#5 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('start')
#6 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xx/magentodev.xxx.de/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Since the module is built-in, reinstalling is not an option. What else can I do?

Comment: Possibly because of your internal ip `http://192.168....', 'http://192.168....'`

Comment: @tecjam sorry, updated the question. I accidentally took the log of my test environment

Comment: Do you have extra fields in your checkout? Any third party extensions affecting the checkout? Are we working with unmodified core files? Is this in sandbox mode or production mode? Did you confirm with paypal that all the api requests have been enabled?

Comment: @kab8609 no, not yet. Not that I know of, I disabled the output of all extensions other than Mage_*, didn't cange anything. Yes, core files, however it is a custom template. Tried sandbox and production, no change. I'm going to call them tomorrow, I'll ask for that. Thanks for your ideas! I'll check back when I know more

Answer (score 3):

I did some research. It appears the php setting `arg_separator.output` must be set to `&`, otherwise the PayPal Server will not even look at your request.
Many Webservers already have it set up like this, however WAMPP (which my hoster appears to be using) does not.

In my opinion, the cleanest way to do this is to add the following to the `.htaccess` in the Magento root.

> # needed for paypal api url bug with &
>   php_value arg_separator.output "&"

However, you can also just change your `php.ini` to apply this adjustment globally.